Should we introduce a [rope-burning] tag? And should any of these be closed as duplicates?
We have a bunch of questions involving variants of the classical puzzle about measuring specific periods of time by burning ropes:

Burning ropes as timers (the original)
Burning ropes as timers - How many time intervals can be measured? (a generalisation)
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1959/5373 (a duplicate and now deleted)
How can I solve my meditation problem? (a variant, duplicate of the generalisation)
I need to measure exactly half an hour (another duplicate)
Two Fuses Burn for 45 Minutes (another duplicate)
Two burning ropes measure 5 minutes (a variant)
Two ropes and 45 mins (another duplicate)
Burning two fuses of variable length (another duplicate)
Using burning ropes as timers (another generalisation)
Using burning ropes as timer - how to measure 1 hour and 8 minutes with 3 ropes? (a variant)
Measure time with 2 ropes (a variant, duplicate of the generalisation)
How do you measure exactly 31 minutes by burning the ropes? (another variant)

This is practically a whole genre of puzzles at this point. Should we create a tag for all these? I suggest rope-burning, even though a few of the questions involve candles etc instead of ropes, because the classic version is usually posed in terms of ropes, but feel free to pose alternative names if you agree with creating a tag but don't like the name "rope burning".
On a related note, there's a lot of duplicates in the list above, but should any of the still-open ones also be closed as duplicates? Especially given the two more-general puzzles which might be broad enough to cover some variants too (and are either of them duplicates of each other?) I want to ask about this rather than just voting to close, because my gold tag badges give me superpowers that should be exercised with great care in duplicate closing.
